# What are some simple Disqus like commenting systems for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I really don't like Disqus, Livefyre, etc as I think they're bloated. Also, I'd like to store comments in our own DB and have full layout flexibility.

I have googled but to my suprise found no good/well maintained alternatives. https://github.com/the-teacher/the_comments comes close but not fully there (and is Rails 4 only).

Does anybody know of any simple commenting system(s) for a Rails web app?

Requirements:

- Rails 3 + 4 support (as we will be upgrading to Rails 4 soon)
- Preferably has nested/threaded comments
- Akismet or similar spam detection so moderation is not needed
- Mail notification to commenters about new comments/replies
- Should allow people not registered as users in our app to comment as well, maybe (but not necessarily) through login via Facebook, their Google account or similar - or no login at all.

Thanks :)

Comment: what makes them bloated? all the extra functionality that you want to add anyway? >_>

Comment: Different things really and I don't remember them all but for Disqus I can't disable the Community tab, for example. But my other points are more important: store comments in our own db and full layout flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

**[Juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia)** is from [Phusion Software](http://www.phusion.nl/), the folks behind [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/). And it is open source.

Comment: Thanks - I did actually see Juvia but it lacks mail notification to commenters about new comments/replies ref. https://github.com/phusion/juvia#todo

Comment: @rassom: it's open-source. So you could add support for this and everyone will thank you. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If I had the skills I definately would :)

Comment: @rassom if you have rails skills, you have the skills to add this feature :) Believe in yourself!!

Answer (score 1):

Try out [act_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading). Its pretty simple to use.

This gem is for Rails 3 and later versions only. And it covers up most of your requirements.

Comment: A lot of answers can become invalid for a variety of reasons. The goal was to answer the question at the time given correct? If that goal is accomplished then nitpicking such answers is useless, a waste of time, and detrimental to the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the already mentioned [Juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) you can count with [opinio](https://github.com/Draiken/opinio) as alternative. Opinio works only with Rails 3 at the moment and as notice the development seems stalled.
After more research I've found those alternatives to work with Rails 4:

[The Comments](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_comments) and [Commontator](https://github.com/lml/commontator)

Comment: Are you sure? Last activity is 8 months ago and Rails 4 is probably only a couple of months away for us, so I'd be gamling to go with opinio.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of The ruby tool box.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_comments

Juvia, Acts as commentable with threading both seem to be the most popular. Both seem to be actively maintained.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately none of them live up to the requirements listed.

Comment: cool, hope you come right!